# Binding a TextBoxFor to a value of Dictionary<CultureInfo, string> for localization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In an ASP.NET MVC 5 web application, I have a `Title` string property in my model which is easily bound to a `TextBoxFor`.

However, because of localization needs, I turned the `Title` property into a `Dictionary<CultureInfo, string>`. I've already read around the net that I can bind the `TextBoxFor` to, say, `Model.Title[new CultureInfo("en-US")]`.

**Question #1:** am I correct when I assume I can also bind to `Model.Title[Model.CurrentLanguage]` (or another variable holding the relevant `CultureInfo`)?

The main problem arises when there is no localization yet, i.e., I'm asking for a given localization for the first time. The dictionary does not contain the key yet, so the binding fails with an exception.

**Question #2:** how could I manage the missing key case? I know I could pre-fill the dictionary with all needed cultures having an empty or null string, but I would really rather not do that, as it removes flexibility, and it would create many entries in each dictionary while I may only need one or two.

**EDIT**
Maybe it wasn't clear from the question, but the localizations I'm talking about are user data, and will be read/written from/to a database. They are not application resources.

Comment: Why not you set default key for CultureInfo?

Comment: @BornToCode I'm not sure what you refer to. Are you suggesting that I pre-fill the culture right before I use it? For example, if I want the user to fill the current language (say en-US), I should add en-US so that the key-value pair already exists when Razor tries to bind to it? But what if the form doesn't get submitted? How would I remove that?

Comment: Its still not clear what your needs are. Why would you want to use a dictionary? Is the user allowed to edit the "title" textbox for multiple cultures? Do you just want localizable titles or localizable values? If its just a single value in the culture of the user then return that from your controller in the normal way and write it back using the thread culture which you can bind using the web.config. However you slice this the view is probably the wrong place to put the logic on missing cultures or filtering cultures, do that in the controller or a custom culture/resource service.

Comment: I need the user to input several strings (title, description, title of the pictures, etc.) into multiple languages. This much localizable content cannot be modeled with a `TitleEN`, `TitleFR`, `TitleIT`... approach, that's why I'm using a dictionary. While the view may not be concerned with "missing languages", still it must be given the current localization for a given language.

Answer (score 0):

IMO I would go into **resource files** rather than dictionary way of localization. Just like here: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/localization.html

In this way even if you don't have, let's say, fr version of you localized string (no xxx.fr.resx file), **it will return default string** (which will be the one in main resource file - the one without culture - xxx.resx)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, I need to read and write the localizations from a database, as they will be user data rather than application data. Your suggestions can't be applied.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like you're doing the decision-making in the wrong place. Rather than passing a dictionary containing titles for different cultures, you should do your culture/title selection in your controller and pass only what you need to the view. Then you can bind to a `String` title.

Comment: My view will be collecting the localizations with a form. The user may input two languages or more at a time. As such, my model needs to keep track of them all, so that they can later be handled as necessary. I already do as you suggest in the frontend, where only one language is needed.